# The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

Tags: methods, double

iam doing an android project based on location...but it shows some errors as

The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

Source:

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location paramLocation)
          {
            this.lati = Double.valueOf(paramLocation.getLatitude());
            this.longi = Double.valueOf(paramLocation.getLongitude());
            if (this.c.moveToFirst()) {
              do
              {
                double d1 = this.longi.doubleValue() - Double.parseDouble(this.c.getString(3));
                double d2 = 1000.0D * (1.609344D * (1.1515D * (60.0D * rad2deg(Math.acos(Math.sin(deg2rad(this.lati.doubleValue())) * Math.sin(deg2rad(Double.parseDouble(this.c.getString(2)))) + Math.cos(deg2rad(this.lati.doubleValue())) * Math.cos(deg2rad(Double.parseDouble(this.c.getString(2)))) * Math.cos(deg2rad(d1)))))));
                if ((d2 >= 0.0D) && (d2 <= 11.0D)) {
                  profilematching(this.c.getString(1));
                }
                //Log.d("distance", d2);//error in this line (.d)
              } while (this.c.moveToNext());
            }
          }
```

Comment: Convert the double `d2` to string first.  The error explains the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Log.d() appears to take 2 strings as parameters but you are supplying a string and a double, so Java complains.

You need to convert d2 to a string first.

Try String.valueOf(d2) as a parameter instead